# Can 'click' change an attribute for a nested group?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a circle packing diagram in which many of the top most circles (the leaves) have titles in common.

I would like to add an interaction which highlights every leaf with a common title when a user clicks on any one leaf. So, for instance, if this data set had say 1000 leaves a user could click on any leaf labeled 'CD 19' and easily see all the other 'CD 19' leaves.

I am doing this for my own edification. I have a half-working solution. I would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction or any explanation why my solution isn't working.

here is my naive solution:

group the leaves by name using d3.nest and .object.

```
const nodes = packLayout(root).descendants()
const nameNest = d3.nest().key(d => d.data.name).object(nodes);
```

now nameNest returns an array of objects with the same name, when passed a name as a key.

```
console.log(nameNest['CD 19']) // => Array(3)
```

then use .forEach(...) to set a common attribute on each member of the array.

```
nameNest['CD 19'].forEach(item => item.r = 50)
```

this has the desired effect. All the circles labeled 'CD 19' get a radius of 50. But what I want to do is turn this snipped of code into a function and then pass that function into an event on my circles as follows:

```
const namez = d => nameNest[d.data.name]
                    .forEach(item => item.r = 50)
...

const circles = nodesEnter
       .append('circle')
       ...
       .on('click', d => namez(d));
```

this does not work. cosnole.log(d => namez(d)) returns 'undefined'.

However when I take off the .forEach(...) console.log(d => namez(d)) returns the expected array of objects with the same name as the node I click. So why can't I use .forEach to modify the array returned by namez(d) from within .on()?

here is my code: [bl.ocks: circle packing diagram with common node names](https://bl.ocks.org/AveryBurke/3d0eb121725610af513afb145549073e/9c4ecc225784f9f1874e66b5532130a840e227e3)

Comment: It's very hard to debug a code we cannot run. So, please take your time and put your JS code and the JSON data in this editor: https://blockbuilder.org (put the JS in a script at the bottom of the body and the JSON as a variable or, since you're using d3.json, click "add a new file"). That way we can help you better.

Comment: thanks Gerardo! I edited my post and added a link to the code on bl.ocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code **is** working! However, you're just changing the data, not the actual SVG elements.

For changing the circles you have to repaint them. For instance:

```
.on('click', d => {
    namez(d);
    circles.attr('r', d => d.r)
});
```

Here is the updated code: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/raw/3caee8c936d1cb3b98cce0706d52d890/f1a38bf56af9a66f418cc08b55f04a64b3c4b494/

Comment: holy cow! thanks Gerardo. Your fix to my code works and now I know what I was missing. I really appreciate the help -Avery